# handling response in fetch command javascript

Tags: javascript, fetch, response

I am new in javascript.
this is my code

```
fetch("myurl", {
  "headers": {
    "accept": "*/*",
    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,fa;q=0.8,tr;q=0.7,de;q=0.6",
    "content-type": "text/plain",
    "sec-ch-ua": "\" Not;A Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"91\", \"Chromium\";v=\"91\"",
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
    "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin"
  },
  "referrer": "Something",
  "referrerPolicy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin",
  "body": "callCount=1\nnextReverseAjaxIndex=0\nc0-scriptName=AjaxManager\nc0-methodName=saveMMTPOrder\nc0-id=0\nc0-param0=string:136BAAEEAB954FF73CA1723B07BB866A\nc0-param1=string:\nc0-param2=string:IRO3DCAZ0001\nc0-param3=string:15890078816297%20%20\nc0-param4=string:V\nc0-param5=string:500\nc0-param6=string:0\nc0-param7=string:\nc0-param8=string:26523\nc0-param9=string:L\nc0-param10=string:J\nc0-param11=string:\nc0-param12=number:94003\nc0-param13=string:2\nc0-param14=number:1622605205661\nc0-param15=string:\nc0-param16=string:-1\nc0-param17=string:1\nc0-param18=null:null\nc0-param19=boolean:false\nc0-param20=string:1\nbatchId=9\ninstanceId=1\npage=%2FmmtpOrder.do%3F0.42751738595872735\nscriptSessionId=YFe7h23EAe~OyKWGJDfDtCxusD5EkutPaDn/zIwPaDn-*5z6wcPhx\n",
  "method": "POST",
  "mode": "cors",
  "credentials": "include"
});
```

Questions:

1)How can I  handle response
2)How can I run the fetch command every 2000 miliseconds.

Thank you

Comment: `fetch()` returns a promise. Use `.then()` to process the response.

Comment: This should be shown in every Fetch tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

```
setInterval(function() {
    // here put the fetch. it will be executed every 2 seconds
}, 2000)
```

usually fetching is done like this :

```
const res = await fetch({...})
// if it returns json data you can get it like this
const json = await res.json()
// then do whatever with it
```

Answer (score 0):

For handling the response you can use your fetch API as below -

```
fetch("myUrl", {
  headers: {
         ...
  }
})
.then((response) => { 
  //use response here directly 
});
```

For calling the API after every 2 seconds you can use the Web API, setInterval -

```
let intervalId = setInterval( () => {
   //put your fetch call here.
}, 2000);
```

You can also use the `intervalId` returned by the `setInterval` method to clear/cancel the interval by passing it to the `clearInterval()` method.